# Get a count of each value from every column at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I tried to see similar questions but none are helping in solving this the efficient way.

The thing is I have a table with columns like this:

[image: table with 3 columns]

I want to count the occurrences of the values in each column but for all the columns of the table, not only one.

I want to get something like this:

```
p7     |  p7_count | p9 | p9_count
B      |   1       | A  |  2
A      |   1       | E  |  1
C      |   1
```

But I'm only able to get this using a single query for each one like:

```
SELECT p9, count(*) AS p9_Count
FROM respostas 
GROUP by p9
ORDER BY p9_Count DESC
```

But the result I get is:

[image: p9 column occurrences count]
[image: p9 column occurrences count]

Is there a way to do this for all the columns instead of having to do it for each one separately and get the result separately?

Comment: When you say *"I want to get something like this"*, you present two separate query results. If you want to have it in one query, what would you want it to look like?

Comment: How about output like `col_name, col_value, count`?

Comment: i would like to have that 2 separate query results on the same table.
I edited the question a bit. Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the kind of thing you were picturing. It gets kind of messy but you can extend it by adding to the coalesces. To get it to work with a row_number function (for MySQL) I've converted it to use a subquery instead. This is not going to be even remotely efficient when the number of rows gets large because SQL isn't the right tool for this job.

```
select
    p1, p1_count, p2, p2_count, p3, p3_count
from
(
    select
        p1, p1_count,
        (
            select count(*) from
                (SELECT p1, count(*) AS p1_Count FROM respostas GROUP by p1) as t2
            where
                    t2.p1_Count <= t1.p1_Count
                or (t2.p1_Count  = t1.p1_Count and t2.p1 <= t1.p1)
        ) as rownum
    from (SELECT p1, count(*) AS p1_Count FROM respostas GROUP by p1) as t1
) as tt1

    full outer join

(
    select
        p2, p2_count,
        (
            select count(*) from
                (SELECT p2, count(*) AS p2_Count FROM respostas GROUP by p2) as t2
            where
                    t2.p2_Count <= t1.p2_Count
                or (t2.p2_Count  = t1.p2_Count and t2.p2 <= t1.p2)
        ) as rownum
    from (SELECT p2, count(*) AS p2_Count FROM respostas GROUP by p2) as t2
) as tt2
    on tt2.rownum = tt1.rownum

    full outer join

(
    select
        p3, p3_count,
        (
            select count(*) from
                (SELECT p3, count(*) AS p3_Count FROM respostas GROUP by p3) as t2
            where
                    t2.p3_Count <= t1.p3_Count
                or (t2.p3_Count  = t1.p3_Count and t2.p3 <= t1.p3)
        ) rownum
    from (SELECT p3, count(*) AS p3_Count FROM respostas GROUP by p2) as t3
) as tt3
    on tt3.rownum = coalesce(tt1.rownum, tt2.rownum)

order by
    coalesce(tt1.rownum, tt2.rownum, tt3.rownum)
```

Comment: I tried working this on phpmyadmin and i guess it didn't like the row_number() over since it says there's a syntax error near that code.

Comment: I guess I didn't see the mysql tag.

Comment: @Rasec I made some edits that might work. I'll confess that I haven't really tested it though.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this with `union all`.  It is a little unclear exactly what you want.  Perhaps this is close:

```
select p, max(p7cnt) as p7cnt, max(p8cnt) as p8cnt, max(p9cnt) as p9cnt
from ((select p7 as p, count(*) as p7cnt, 0 as p8cnt, 0 as p9cnt
       from respostas
       group by p7
      ) union all
      (select p8, 0 as p7cnt, count(*) as p8cnt, 0 as p9cnt
       from respostas
       group by p8
      ) union all
      (select p9, 0 as p7cnt, 0 as p8cnt, count(*) as p9cnt
       from respostas
       group by p9
      )
     ) ppp
group by p;
```

Comment: I liked this idea but it's not counting as i would expect it. It only shows 1 on the count for each column value.